# What does 'vetted' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Finally - and most significantly - at least two shipments of MANPADS
>   have arrived into northern #Syria, to **“vetted”** FSA groups.

Oxford defines it as:

> make a careful and critical examination of (something).

How does it fit into this context?

For more details, the original context: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Vetted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vet#vet__10)*** refers to the FSA (Free Syrian Army) groups that are considered reliable.

> - ***If something is vetted, it is checked carefully to make sure that it is acceptable to people in authority.*** [mainly British] [be V-ed] :
>
>   - He can find no trace of a rule requiring research to be vetted before publication. [be V-ed] ⇒ All objects are vetted by a distinguished panel of experts. [V n] ⇒ He had not been allowed to read any book until his mother had vetted it.

Collins Dictionary

Comment: *Vetted* has the same meaning in the US.